# How to sort ArrayList of model type according to date (a string type variable in ArrayList)?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to sort an ArrayList of model type, ArrayList jobCards according to string type of date field called dueDate.

I tried adding the following in model.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(@NonNull TodayModel o) 
{
    return o.newDueDate.compareTo(this.newDueDate);
}
```

And then applying

Collections.sort(jobCards);

Comment: Then you need show your code first here! After we can sort your `ArrayList`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you have the right idea, your method isn't wired up to the IComparable interface.

Define your **JobCards** class like so.

```
public class JobCards : IComparable<JobCards> {
```

The Visual Studio editor will highlight **IComparable**, offering two options to correct it. Choose **Implement explicitly**, and let the editor add the stub method. which will be called **IComparable.CompareTo**; note the difference between that and what you have. Then, replace the statement that throws a NotImplementedException with your code, and you should be good to go.